# Paginate Firebase rest api

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase REST API to get my data. I am getting data like

```
[ {
  "date_time" : "2018-01-03 03:30:00",
  "domestic" : "0",
  "f_key" : "",
  "id" : 2,
  "international" : "1",
  "league" : "0",
  "match_number" : "One-day practice match",
  "men" : "1",
  "odi" : "1",
  "result" : "Pakistan won by 120 runs",
  "series_name" : "Pakistan tour of New Zealand, 2018",
  "status" : "2",
  "t1_short_name" : "NZ",
  "t20" : "0",
  "t2_short_name" : "PAK",
  "team1" : "New Zealand",
  "team1_flag" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/ce_flags/nz.png",
  "team2" : "Pakistan",
  "team2_flag" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/ce_flags/pak.png",
  "test" : "0",
  "venue" : "Saxton Oval, Nelson",
  "women" : "0"
}, {
  "date_time" : "2018-01-03 03:30:00",
  "domestic" : "0",
  "f_key" : "",
  "id" : 159,
  "international" : "1",
  "league" : "0",
  "match_number" : "One-day practice match",
  "men" : "1",
  "odi" : "1",
  "result" : "Pakistan won by 120 runs",
  "series_name" : "Pakistan tour of New Zealand, 2018",
  "status" : "2",
  "t1_short_name" : "NZ",
  "t20" : "0",
  "t2_short_name" : "PAK",
  "team1" : "New Zealand",
  "team1_flag" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/ce_flags/nz.png",
  "team2" : "Pakistan",
  "team2_flag" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/ce_flags/pak.png",
  "test" : "0",
  "venue" : "Saxton Oval, Nelson",
  "women" : "0"
} ]
```

but when i am trying to paginate them its not working i am using like this

```
https://fir-resttest-4e895.firebaseio.com/Fixtures/All.json?orderBy=%22date_time%22&limitToFirst=2&startAfter=10&print=pretty
```

how can i use pagination here please  help me to sort out this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Database queries do not support an offset parameter like you might be used to.

The value that you pass for `startAt` must be a value of the type/format of the property you have in `orderBy`. Since you order on `date_time` the value of `startAt` must be a valid `date_time`:

This will give you all items starting at `2018-01-03 03:30:00`.

```
orderBy="date_time"&limitToFirst=2&startAt="2018-01-03 03:30:00"
```

Also note that the parameter is called `startAt`, not `startAfter`.

Some examples for your data set:

- [`startAt="2018-06-01 20:30:00"`](https://fir-resttest-4e895.firebaseio.com/Fixtures/All.json?orderBy=%22date_time%22&limitToFirst=2&startAt=%222018-06-01%2020:30:00%22&print=pretty)
- [`startAt="2018-06-01"`](https://fir-resttest-4e895.firebaseio.com/Fixtures/All.json?orderBy=%22date_time%22&limitToFirst=2&startAt=%222018-06-01%22&print=pretty) (so you can also start at a substring)

Comment: That seems to have nothing to do with this question. If you have a problem of your own, please post a new question with the [minimal complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).